# Dealing with root node which has a different namespace

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

XSLT 1.0.

Source XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<playlist xmlns="http://xspf.org/ns/0/" version="1">
    <trackList>
        <track>
            <location>1/Kosheen/Independence/01;Addict.flac</location>
            <title>Addict</title>
            <creator>Kosheen</creator>
            <album>Independence</album>
            <duration>286000</duration>
            <image>1/Kosheen/Independence/cover.jpg</image>
        </track>
    </trackList>
</playlist>
```

XSLT stylesheet file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="no" />

    <xsl:template match="/playlist/trackList">
        <tracks>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="track"/>
        </tracks>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/playlist/trackList/track">
        <track>
            <xsl:copy-of select="location"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="title"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="creator"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="album"/>
        </track>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Unless I remove the `xmlns` attribute from the root `playlist` node the templates in the stylesheet are not applied.

I would like the output XML file to be free of the XSPF namespace.

How should I update the stylesheet to deal with the xspf namespace of the root node?

Comment: If you search for "default XSLT namespace" you will find 676 answers to this question, most of them correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a declaration for your namespace and assign a prefix so you can refer to the elements in your source document:

```
xmlns:ns1="http://xspf.org/ns/0/"
```

Since your result document is also in the same namespace, you declare it as the default namespace as well:

```
xmlns="http://xspf.org/ns/0/"
```

Now you refer to the elements in your source XML with the prefix: `ns1:playlist`, for example.

Here is your stylesheet with the namespaces added:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns="http://xspf.org/ns/0/" 
    xmlns:ns1="http://xspf.org/ns/0/"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="ns1"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="no" />

    <xsl:template match="/ns1:playlist/ns1:trackList">
        <tracks>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ns1:track"/>
        </tracks>
     </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/ns1:playlist/ns1:trackList/ns1:track">
        <track>
            <xsl:copy-of select="ns1:location"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="ns1:title"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="ns1:creator"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="ns1:album"/>
        </track>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Update**

If your result must be in `no-namespace`, you can remove the unprefixed `xmlns`, but you won't be able to use copy-of (since it copies the full node, including the namespaces - the `xmlns` declarations will appear in each node). If your child elements have only text, you can replace:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="ns1:location"/>
```

with

```
<location><xsl:value-of select="ns1:location"/></location>
```

Then you can remove the default `xmlns` from `<xsl:stylesheet>`.

Comment: Brilliant - thanks. The result's root 'tracks' node has the xspf.org xmlns and xmlns:xspf attributes/namespace - is it possible to get rid of these?

Comment: You can get rid of the prefixed one adding `exclude-result-prefixes="ns1"` to the `<xsl:stylesheet>` since it's not used in the result. I edited that above.

Comment: You *can* get rid of the `xmlns`. In that case you can remove the `xmlns` from `xsl:stylesheet`, but also would have to selectively copy your nodes (not using `copy-of`) since you would have to get rid of the namespace. If you remove the `xmlns` from the default result tree, `<track>` and `<tracks>` will be in no-namespace, but the nodes you copied with `copy-of` will be in your xspf namespace.